# Swift MKMapView overlays nil

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

When I access overlays property it returns nil, but I expect to get empty array. Is it bug in sdk, or I am doing something wrong?

[image]

```
func clearRoute(name: String)
{
    var overlayToRemove = [MKOverlay]()
    var o = self.mapView.overlays
    for overlay in o {
        if let overlay = overlay as? MKPolyline {
            if overlay.title == name { overlayToRemove.append(overlay) }
        }
    }

    self.mapView.removeOverlays(overlayToRemove)
}
```

[image]